# How to determine which pin raises a interrupt from EXTI in W7500/P?

Tags: interrupt

I'm trying to figure out how to use W7500/P chip (from wiznet).

For the EXTI function, I did not find a register like EXTI_PR in ST mcu. So I do not know how to determine which pin really raises a interrupt as all pin use the same EXTI.

Could anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Which ST MCU are you using? Please add some details.

Comment: Hello, it's not ST MCU. Its W7500/P from wiznet.